# Why doesn't the copy constructor get called?

Tags: c++, templates, copy-constructor

I have this code for copying a polygon class. The problem I have is that in the end the vertices point to the original polygon class location. Since the copy constructor does not seem to be invoked. Why is that ?

```
Polygon::Polygon(const Polygon &aPolyToCopy)
{
int i;
vertices = new Vertex[aPolyToCopy.count];

for (i=0;i<aPolyToCopy.count;i++)
{
    vertices[i].x = aPolyToCopy.vertices[i].x;
    vertices[i].y = aPolyToCopy.vertices[i].y;
}

count = aPolyToCopy.count;
}
```

In a list template I do this

```
template <class T, int i>
bool SortedVector<T, i>::add ( const T& v )
{
myClass[myCurrent] = v; //Copy constructor not called ?
myCurrent++;

return true;
}
```

The template is

```
 template <class T, int i>
 class SortedVector
 {
 public:
   int maxSize;
   T myClass[i];
   int myCurrent;

   SortedVector();
   ~SortedVector();
   bool add ( const T& v );
};
```

Comment: This is an assignment operation so assignment operator should be called, not the copy constructor.

Comment: I think thats the job of assignment operator, not Copy constructor.

Comment: You are assigning `myClass[myCurrent] = v;` so assign operator is being called and not copy constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing an **assignment**, you **don't construct a new object** here. If you define a custom copy constructor, you **also need to overload operator=**

See http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/911-the-copy-constructor-and-overloading-the-assignment-operator/ for example.

If you would do something like `x = Polygon(y)`, then your copy constructor would be called (followed by the default `operator=`). But don't use this workaround, just provide your  `operator=`.

Comment: "*If you define a custom copy constructor, you also need to overload operator=*" - this is a good design guideline but it has nothing to do with the question asked

Comment: @icepack How so? The OP's problem comes from the fact they didn't follow this guideline.

Comment: "*If you would do something like x = Polygon(y), then your copy constructor would be called (followed by the default operator=)*" - unless copy elision is used by the compiler

Comment: @Angew no, the problem is a confusion between copy constructor and assignment operator functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I think a problem in your `Polygon` class is that you have a `vertices` data member, which seems to be a *raw pointer* to a `Vertex`, used to store a *raw array* allocated with `new[]`:

> vertices = new Vertex[aPolyToCopy.count];

You may need to overload also `operator=` (and the destructor), not only the copy constructor (see [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)); you haven't showed all the code of your `Polygon` class, so it's not clear if you defined proper copy assignment and destruction.

Note that you will simplify your code if you use a robust RAII container class like **`std::vector`**.
Just add a "`std::vector<Vertex> vertices;`" data member instead of a "`Vertex* vertices`" data member, and `std::vector` will take care of copy, cleanup, etc. You don't need to do anything: it's all automatically managed by `std::vector`.

```
#include <vector>    // for std::vector

class Polygon
{
  std::vector<Vertex> vertices;

public:
  explicit Polygon(size_t vertexCount)
    : vertices(vertexCount) // Build a polygon with specified vertices
  {}

  //  
  // Compiler generated copy constructor, operator= and destructor are fine.
  //
};
```

In general, in C++ try to build classes assembling together convenient RAII building blocks like `std::vector` and other direct resource managers.